# Has PAZ satellite been launched?

Tags: earth-observation, satellites, radar

There are several mentions in the net about Spanish radar satellite called "PAZ", which should work in tandem with German TerraSAR-X and should have been launched in 2015. But most results I can find talk about plans, and no real announcement that it has been successfully launched. Anyone knows the current status of it?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, remove it and place it on [Space.se]. adding some links to your question may help too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The launch was scheduled for 2017 using a DNPER launch vehicle. It seems that the contract contract between Kosmotras and Hisdesat [was canceled](http://spaceflights.news/?launch=dnepr-%E2%80%A2-paz) and that resulted in an uncertain launch date. The satellite has been finished since 2013 and it has been waiting for over 3 years to be launched.

[image: Paz satellite][Source](http://ep01.epimg.net/politica/imagenes/2016/07/19/actualidad/1468951759_250653_1468952706_noticia_normal_recorte1.jpg)

The dispute between Russia and Ukraine resulted in EU imposing sanctions on Moscow. As a result, Russian President Vladimir Putin supposedly signed a secret decree halting launches of the Dnepr rocket (based on the Soviet-era R-36M missile that was made in Ukraine). It also affected the launch of several satellites of the Iridium constellation. With the Russian government withholding approval for the launch, everything felt apart and now the parent company ([hisdeSAT](http://www.hisdesat.es/eng/satelites_observ-paz.html)) has to find another launch platform. [The two main candidates are the Soyuz rocket from Roscosmos and the Falcon rocket from Space-X, but the cost of either alternative is much higher.](http://elpais.com/elpais/2016/07/20/inenglish/1469002393_087157.html)